# Cocos2d-x android 5.0 clipping node not working

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I've discovered that clipping node is not working as expected on android 5.0.
I'm using cocos2d-x 3.4 final, compiling on mac os x yosemite with ndk r10d (tried r10c and r9d too).

Cpp-tests compiling without any problem. But going in Node: Clipping category shows that something's very wrong. For example:

On Android 4.4:

[image: android 4.4 screenshot]

But on android 5.0:

[image: android 5.0 screenshot]

The same problem occurs with other tests in this category.

Comment: Makalele, it seems like a genuine bug. report it on cocos2d-x git. I am not sure what is the reason for this post.

Comment: I have a game on cocos2d-x 3.3 where I have used clipping node with no problem,even on android 5.0 using ndk r10d.

Comment: also, clipping node works on stencil buffer of OpenGL API, make sure it's not disabled.

Comment: How did you do that?